# VSCode jsconfig and intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've spent hours trying to get my plain JS project in VS code to be able to use intellisense. It only works when I have multiple files open at once, otherwise intellisense cannot find the associated classes. I am using a `jsconfig.json` file in `/src` but I cannot get any of it to do anything at all, no matter what properties I have tried. My project structure is

```js
/project
  /src
    /app
     app.js
    /views
      /home
       home.js
      /about
       about.js
```

I really want `app.js` to be able to see classes in those view folders (plus all the other folders in src). ie

```js
class App {
   somefunction(){
     HomeView.dosomething(); // want to be able to ctrl click to HomeView and dosomething()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what changed, maybe VSCode needed 20 minutes to figure things out, but eventually this simple `jsconfig.js` file did the trick, placed in `/src`

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```